# What would you want in a self-hosted project support/information web app?

Tags: project-management, forum, bug-tracking

My next project will be a lightweight PHP alternative to Trac, since Trac is often confusing to install and is often a little too big or feature-rich for smaller project.

Features planned so far:

- Wiki
- Bug tracker
- Forum(s)
- Static pages (easily edited of course)
- Markdown support
- No code repo hosting (I consider this a feature since most people would prefer to use a 3rd party such as GitHub for the actual code hosting)

My question: if you were to use a self-hosted app for making a website about one of your open source projects, what would you want? Is there anything on that list that's missing? Would you absolutely require the ability to actually host the code repo on the site itself, or would you be ok hosting the code elsewhere (Google Code, GitHub, BitBucket), and using the site only to upload major versions?

**Summary: if you were to use a self-hosted app to provide info and support for an open source project of yours, what would you want it to be like?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redmine is my current favorite, I usually install it via [BitNami](http://bitnami.org/)

Comment: I like Redmine, but it has a lot meant for project management (read: meant for internal use) web app as opposed to what I'm going for which is meant for the general public downloading public.

What are some parts of Redmine that make you a fan?

Comment: what makes me a fan: very simple out of the box Git integration :) with repo browsing + excelent forensic diffing and all, wiki and use of ruby which I intend to learn more of soon..but most of all simplicity, I use trac at work, so I totally agree with it being difficult to follow in setup and even daily use..redmine+git means I just code and its all clear as day when I commit push without having to think about tickets 

(which come in handy in big complicated teams and requirements only IMO)